# Evaluate Matrix on parametrized indices

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a matrix, say `F= magic(8)`, whose elements are indicesed by x and y in 1:N in both dimensions.
I have a (1-D) parameter that specifies a subset of the possible coordinates (x,y), i.e. x(b(k)) and y(b(k)) with size(b)=[M,1] give me 
M coordinates (x(b(k)),y(b(k))) where I want to evaluate F. 
Is it possible to access `F((x(b(k)),y(b(k))))` for k=1:M without writing a for loop? 
I am looking a quicker solution that running the loop

```
F= magic(8)
for k=1:M
    do_something_on(F((x(b(k)),y(b(k)))))
end
```

Note that if I write

```
F((x(b(1:M)),y(b(1:M)))
```

I get a M x M matrix, where the diagonal elements are the ones I am looking for, but I rather do not build the whole M x M matrix to extract the diagonal.

Comment: use `sub2ind` to get your indices.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `F(x(b), y(b))` that is giving you a matrix, you can use:

```
arrayfun(@(bk) F(x(bk), y(bk)), b)
```

or:

```
F(sub2ind(size(F), x(b), y(b)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have probably found the solution, I have to use the vectorized form for the matrix F, that is `F(:)`, and evaluate it in `(y-1)*size(F,1)+x`, i.e.

```
F((y(b)-1)*size(F,1)+x(b))
```

Comment: This is the same as what `sub2ind` does, only this is a little faster